# Why is my kitchen LED lighting flickering

Tags: led, dimmer-switch

My kitchen light is blinking, is there a way to find out what is causing it and how do I fix it? Could the problem be with the dimmer?
See below images of LED array, LED driver and dimmer switch, and here's a short [video of the LED blinking](https://photos.app.goo.gl/KzjbHiUhBTGkjhBI3).

I'm a complete novice to LEDs and lighting, so a simplified answer would be great, thanks :)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Has it been like this since the LED fixture was installed or did it start later?

Comment: @DoxyLover, it has been like this since I moved into the apartment half a year ago :P I was kinda busy and lazy and only now I got around to it..

Comment: yes, it's the dimmer. that driver is not meant to be dimmed. i bet it doesn't dim very effectively does it (much of the dim range does nothing)? you will need to replace the driver to dim them, but the dimming would be digital, and thus your dimmer switch still won't be a way to dim them. I've not seen a driver that samples the AC waveform to determine older-dimmer settings, whilst still converting the chopped wave to a variable DC. So, if you want to use that dimmer switch, you need to replace the whole fixture and use a newer (2016+) LED bulb that's designed to play nice with older dimmers.

Comment: @dandavis you should post that as an answer.