# Why is this led light flickering?

Tags: light-fixture, led, dimmer-switch

Related to this question, [link](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/124728/why-is-my-kitchen-led-lighting-flickering), I have a very similar-looking dimmer and light.  The dimmer is very old, at least 20 years, and the light is perhaps 5-8 years old.  It never used to flicker.
This week it began, about a single flicker in a minute (but not regular).

I'm curious what might have caused it to flicker just now, and whether it makes more sense to look for the trouble in the dimmer or the light itself.

Comment: Is there another appliance (furnace, dishwasher, vacuum cleaner, garage door opener...etc) that is turning on when it flickers?

Comment: No, there is not

Comment: it could be dusty, which makes it run hotter, which can trigger the thermal current limiting circuit. It could also be noise on the line from a newly added device; older dimmers might not have a snubber circuit and they often have troubles with capacitive loads (like some LED bulbs and drivers) that they didn't with plain resistive loads (tungsten light bulbs). I would get a new dimmer first; you can potentially use the old one someplace else, depending on what's wrong with your current setup.

Answer (score 1):

After watching the flicker I would guess it is the driver in the light itself.

Older dimmers don’t have much to fail but the driver in the led light is packed with electronics the capacitors if electrolytic are a common failure point and the reason the lights don’t last 30 years.

On some of the big led lights I have installed that have failed I have made repairs and replaced drivers.

For the smaller fixtures I have not found a cost effective source for drivers, some are separate and some on the board if you see a bulging cap or one that has leaked replacing it may solve the flicker.

If yours is separate like the photo it may be worthwhile if you can find one.